# One button relies on the other to be clicked

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I have two buttons in my Android app, and one is supposed to put a number into the phone's native dialer app. The other is meant to take you to a website. However, you can only use the website button if you click the call button. I want my users to be able to select each button independently, not have to wait a few seconds before they can visit the webpage. I'm including my code below.

I have tried everything I can think of, including removing the problematic button from the activity, but I want my users to have the choice of webpage or phone.

```
public class fthactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fthactivity);
        findViewById(R.id.fthcall).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialContactPhone("112345678910");
            }
        });
    }

    private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null)));

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fthweb);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.ca/"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);

            }

        });
    }
}
```

This is my Activity. If anyone needs more code, I would be glad to supply.
Thanks.

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Yes. If you refer to the answer below, it is what made it work. Sorry, I don't know how to make it easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you're calling the method for the second button inside the first. Try this:

```
public class fthactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fthactivity);
        findViewById(R.id.fthcall).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialContactPhone("112345678910");
            }
        });

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fthweb);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.ca/"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);

            }

        });
    }

    private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null)));
    }
}
```

Also when using **Implicit** intents resolve the activity to see if there is an activity that can answer to that intent, otherwise it will break:

```
Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.ca/"));

if (myWebLink.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivity(myWebLink);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! I can't believe I didn't notice that.